# Javascript base javascript loop nr of iterations on php loop ierations

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Consider the following code which takes the time from database, javascript gets the selectbox value and performs a countdown calculation.

```
var seconds = document.getElementById("countTime").textContent;
var seconds = seconds*3600;
function timer() {
 //somecode
}

echo'<td id="countTime" style="">';
                    echo    $days_remaining.$hours_remaining;
                        echo'</td>';
```

This is working like a charm and I'm getting this output

[image]

But here are my problems:

- I'm creating invalid html in  `echo'<td id="countdown"`... ok I can fix this easily by declaring an array and appending that to id like:`<td id="countdown'.$nr." //assume $nr = 1 ++`

  ***BUT***
- My big problem lies in my jscript code the above javascript only works for the 1st td element the `<td>` element is in a loop and the nr of `<td>` elements are based on the number of loop iterations

***THUS***

1. How would I modify the jscript above to return a countdown time inside each `<td>` element? Can I do this `var seconds = document.getElementById( var seconds = document.getElementById("countTime".nr++).value;).innerText;`??
2. It is obvious I would have to make use of a loop but how would I get the number of times the javascript loop should iterate based on the php while loop nr of iterations?
   *I suppose I can count the number of php loop iterations with `$var++` display it in element and get the .innerText value, however this seems awfully inefficient*

Perhaps I am overthinking this but I am stuck...

Comment: Use classes instead of IDs.

Comment: Fair enough but that still doesnt solve my problem

Comment: You don't need to assign ids to the elements with your `$nr` variable: just give them all the same class, e.g. `class="countTime"` and then use [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) and a loop or with jQuery `$(".countTime").each(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Like was mentioned in the comments, use a common class on your `<td>`s. Then change your Javascript to use `querySelectorAll`:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.countTime');
var seconds, i;

// elements now contains an object, that contains all elements
// that have the class 'countTime'

for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    seconds = elements[i].textContent * 3600;
    // etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try manipulate below code in your project hope it works

```
function countDown() {
            let expireDate = document.querySelectorAll('.expire_date');

            let x = [];

            for (let i = 0; i < expireDate.length; i++) {
                x.push(expireDate[i].innerHTML);
            }

            console.log(x)

            for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                const m = i;
                let interval = setInterval(function () {
                    if (!isNaN(Date.parse(x[i]))) {
                        let prevDate = new Date(x[i]).getTime();
                        let now = new Date().getTime();

                        let diff = prevDate - now;
                        console.log(diff)

                        let days = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 86400)) //60 * 60 * 24
                        let hours = Math.floor(diff % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) / (1000 * 60 * 60)) //60 * 60 * 24
                        let min = Math.floor(diff % (1000 * 60 * 60) / (1000 * 60))
                        let secs = Math.floor(diff % (1000 * 60) / 1000)

                        console.log(`${days}d ${hours}hrs ${min}mins ${secs}s`);

                        let displayText = document.querySelectorAll('.countdown');
                        for (let index = 0; index < displayText.length; index++) {
                            const e = index;

                            if (e == i) {
                                displayText[index].innerHTML = `${days}d ${hours}hrs ${min}mins ${secs}s`;
                            }
                        }

                        if (diff < 0) {
                            clearInterval(interval);
                            displayText[index].innerHTML = 'expired'
                        }
                    }
                }, 1000)

            }

        }

        countDown();
```